# Issues with texturing an egg shape - Displace Modifier

Tags: texturing, topology

So I would like to make some textured egg models for 3D printing. I took the default cube, subdivided it and then used the Cast modifier to ensure quads. I then selected the model, assigned the entire model into a Vertex Group. Finally adding the Displace modifier and the texture including another subdivision modifier.

The final result is pictured below. Both top and bottom of the mesh has the exact same crazy pattern as if the texture is squashed?

Where did I go wrong?

Kind regards and thank you in advance. Any advice is appreciated greatly.
[image]
[image]

**Edit**
Without the quads I end up with the tomato topology on both top and bottom on the model.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it's related to the fact that you have 'corners' on the top and bottom where 3 quads come together.  (You can see the 'Y' in the edges at those corners.)  I suspect that they match the original corners of the cube and are where your deformation weirdness happens.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you for the response. So I guess that using the cube is a bad idea for this sort of shape when applying textures?

Comment: I think spheres are just hard to texture no matter how you generate them.  I'm sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: What sort of displacement are you looking for?

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you for pointing out the 3 quads though, that is a useful step in this investigation.

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm looking for a way of consistent displacement for the top and bottom as shown throughout the rest of the model without the craziness as pictured. I've edited the post to show what happens when the topology has triangles on the top instead of quads.